# Definition of the joint spectrum of Hilbert space operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, definition, operator-algebras

I see in [this paper](https://msp.org/pjm/1981/95-1/pjm-v95-n1-p03-s.pdf) the following definition:

[image]

> How ${\bf A''}$ is defined? Is there a relation between $\sigma({\bf A})$  and $\sigma_H({\bf A})$? Note that $\sigma_H({\bf A})$ is defined as:

**Definition:** $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n)\notin \sigma_H({\bf A})$ if there exist operators $U_1,\cdots,U_n,V_1,\cdots,V_n \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ such that
$$\sum_{1\leq k \leq n}U_k(A_k-\lambda_k I)=I\;\hbox{and}\;\;\sum_{1\leq k \leq n}(A_k-\lambda_k I)V_k =I.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double commutant $A''$ is defined as $(A')'$, where
$$
A'=\{T\in B(H):\ TA_j=A_jT,\ j=1,\ldots,n\}
$$
and
$$
A''=\{S\in B(H):\ ST=TS\ \forall T\in A'\}. 
$$
The double commutant is mostly interesting when the original set contains adjoints, because the commutant of a set that contains its adjoints is a von Neumann algebra. I find it weird the way it's used in the paper, but maybe that's just me.

The Double Commutant Theorem says that, if $M\subset B(H)$ is a $*$-algebra, then 
$$
M''=\overline{M}^{\rm sot}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it used it in the paper because this joint spectrum  is equal to the joint approximate point spectrum of commuting normal operators.

Comment: Also I find today that this spectrum is egal to the Harte spectrum in the case of normal operators: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/on-joint-spectra-of-noncommuting-normal-operators/4457C4DD8B65C9B255ADEC99708910CD

Comment: Yes. If the $A_j $ are normal and commuting, then by Fuglede-Putnam you have that $A'$  is a von Neumann algebra and that  $A''$ is an abelian von Neumann algebra. That's why the one-sided condition can be used.

Comment: Dear Professor. Please see the following paper page 3 https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102867217  (because perhaps there is a small problem in the inclusion given in your answer.

Comment: What I said about the inclusion seems to be wrong. I have deleted that paragraph.

Comment: Thank you Professor Martin. Do you think that the definition of the bicommutant joint spectrum requires the  operators $A_k$ to be commuting?

Comment: Not sure. The lack of adjoints makes me unsure if the double commutant is abelian, even when the original tuple is commuting. Maybe it is, and that would make it more reasonable that the definition of $\sigma(A)$ is "one-sided".