# Spectral measure for a finite set of mutually commuting normal operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, spectral-theory

The following question is from Exercise $\S 11.11$ in **A Course in Operator Theory** written by *John B. Conway*:

> Suppose $\{N_1, \cdots, N_p\}$ is a finite set of mutually commuting normal operators in $B(H)$ such that for each $1\leq j, k\leq p$, $N_j N_k^* = N_k^* N_j$. Show that there is a unique spectral measure $E$ defined on a compact subset $X$ of $\mathbb{C}^p$ such that for each $1\leq k \leq p$, we have $$N_k = \int_X z_k\,d E(z)$$ where, for each $z\in\mathbb{C}^p$, $z_k$ is the $k$-the coordinate of $z$

My attempt is to apply the definition of **joint spectrum** introduced in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051935). The definition is that, given a $n$-tuple of commuting normal operators $\{N_1, \cdots, N_p\}$, we say a point $z\in\mathbb{C}^p$ is in their joint spectrum iff for any $U_1, \cdots, U_p, V_1, \cdots, V_p\in B(H)$, we have:

$$
\sum_{i\leq p}U_i (z_i - N_i)\neq I_H,\hspace{1cm} \sum_{i \leq p}(z_i - N_i)V_i \neq I_H
$$

If we use $\Sigma$ to denote the joint spectrum of $\{N_1, \cdots, N_p\}$, whenever $\lambda-N_k$ is invertible, we then have:

$$
(0, 0, \cdots, \lambda, 0, \cdots, 0)\in \mathbb{C}\backslash\Sigma \hspace{0.5cm}\implies\hspace{0.5cm} \lambda\in P_k(\mathbb{C}\backslash\Sigma) \hspace{0.5cm}\implies\hspace{0.5cm} P_k(\Sigma)\subseteq\sigma(N_k) \hspace{0.5cm}\implies\hspace{0.5cm} \Sigma\subseteq\times_{k=1}^p\sigma(N_k)
$$

Then, my questions are:

1. How to show $\Sigma$ is closed? (**p.s.** later in this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123670900558) I found a proof).
2. How to define the desired spectral measure $E$ on $\Sigma$ such that $N_k = \int_{\Sigma}z_k\,d E(z)$ (since possibly $P_k(\Sigma)$ might be properly contained in $\sigma(N_k)$)? When will $\Sigma$ be equal to $\times_{k=1}^p\sigma(N_k)$?
3. Is there a normal operator $M$ defined on another Hilbert space such that the spectral measure of $M$ coincides with the $E$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the following way more straightforward definition of joint spectrum. Consider $\mathcal A=C^*(N_1,\ldots,N_p)$. Then $\mathcal A$ is an abelian C$^*$-algebra, so $\mathcal A\simeq C(X)$ where $X$ is the character space of $\mathcal A$. The joint spectrum is then the set
$$
\sigma(N_1,\ldots,N_p)=\{((\gamma(N_1),\ldots,\gamma(N_p)):\ \gamma\in X\}\subset\prod_{k=1}^p\sigma(N_k).
$$
It follows from the definitions that $\sigma(N_1,\ldots,N_p)$ is homeomorphic to $X$ (as in the single variable case), which gives $\mathcal A\simeq C(\sigma(N_1,\ldots,N_p))$. One can then consider the representation $\rho:C(\sigma(N_1,\ldots,N_p))\to B(H)$ induced by $\rho(z_k)=N_k$. By Theorem IX.1.14 in Conway's *A Course in Functional Analysis* there exists a spectral measure $E$ on the Borel sets of $\sigma(N_1,\ldots,N_p)$ such that
$$
\rho(f)=\int_{\sigma(N_1,\ldots,N_p)}f\,dE.
$$

I think it's almost impossible for the joint spectrum to be equal to the Cartesian product of the spectra. The joint spectrum is more akin as a "curve" (in the $p=2$ case).

Finally, I cannot make sense of your last question. A single operator will have a a spectral measure on a compact subset of $\mathbb C$, whereas the one constructed here is defined over a compact subset of $\mathbb C^p$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! May I ask how do you know that the joint spectrum is equal to the set $\Big\{ \Big(\, (\gamma(N_1), \gamma(N_2), \cdots, \gamma(N_p) \,\Big): \gamma\in X \Big\}$? Also, could you elaborate a bit on what you meant by the joint spectrum is like a "curve"? Do you mean there could exist a continuously changing tuple of $(U_1, U_2, \cdots, U_p)$, and $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \cdots, \lambda_p)$ such that $\sum_{i\leq p}U_i(\lambda_i - N_i)$ is equal to (or distant away from) the identity when $\{U_i\}, \{\lambda_i\}$ is continuously changing?

Comment: Now I realize my last question is not accurate. It is inspired by a theorem in later chapters in the textbook, which states that when $H$ is separable, I can find a self-adjoint $A\in B(H)$ such that $C^*(A)$ contains each $N_i$. I first wonder if I could find a normal operator whose spectral measure coincides with the one defined on $\bigcup_{i\leq p}\sigma(N_i)$. I wonder will this happen when  $\{\sigma(N_i)\}_i$ is mutually disjoint, so that the sum of their spectral measures, which is another spectral measure on $\bigcup_{i\leq p}\sigma(N_i)$, can return a new normal operator.

Comment: I'm defining the joint spectrum that way. It is a way in which it is straightforward to see that it is homeomorphic to the character space of $C^*(N_1,\ldots,N_p)$, so one gets the expected isomorphism $C^*(N_1,\ldots,N_p)\simeq C(\sigma(N_1,\ldots,N_p)$. And it is a direct generalization of what one does in one variable. The definition you used I have to admit I don't understand it (I mean, I understand the terminology and even the analogy with the one-operator case, but it says nothing to me).

Comment: For the $N_j$ to act separately what you need is not that the spectra is dsjoint, but that the spectral measures act on pairwise orthogonal subspaces. That is, you need $E_j(\Delta)E_k(\Delta')=0$ whenever $k\ne j$ and for all $\Delta,\Delta'$. In that case the operators behave as if they were the components of a direct sum.

Comment: I noticed I didn't answer the "curve" question. What I mean is that the Cartesian product of two intervals is a rectangle; but if you have two operators each with spectrum an interval, the joint spectrum is more likely to look like a curve within that rectangle. For instance, suppose that $f,g\in C[0,1]$ satisfy $fg=0$ and both have range $[0,1]$. The characters are the point evaluations. So the joint spectrum is $$\sigma(f,g)=\{(f(x),g(x)):\ x\in[0,1]\}=([0,1]\times\{0\})\cup(\{0\}\times[0,1]).$$

Comment: Thank you again for your detailed explanation! Your definition is indeed more straightforward and it is worth finding out if those two definitions are equivalent. In my point of view, the definition from the paper I quoted is better for seeing how the joint resolvent set geometrically behave.

Comment: Since you mentioned curve, may I ask if you could take a look the question in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4534209 $\hspace{2cm}$ In the case when $C^*(N_1, N_2, \cdots, N_p)\subseteq C^*(N)$, I wonder if I could let the joint spectrum $\sigma(N_1, N_2, \cdots, N_p)$ consist of curves and eventually fill the entire $\sigma(N)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139411/discussion-between-sanae-kochiya-and-martin-argerami).

Comment: I will think about that question. First comment is that the function you propose does not work for (1), because it is not discrete; you want a simple function, as you said before.